# Where to put temporary, non-admin files?

Tags: c#

I have a CSharp Application and I am downloading a temporary file, However I need this program to be run in non-administrator mode and I can only write to C Drive if I have administrator mode on.

What directory is open to writing from programs with no administrator privellages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try [`Path.GetTempPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

[Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is available to all users logged into a machine, regardless of administrative privileges (or lack there of).

> Isolated storage is a data storage
>   mechanism that provides isolation and
>   safety by defining standardized ways
>   of associating code with saved data.
>   Standardization provides other
>   benefits as well. Administrators can
>   use tools designed to manipulate
>   isolated storage to configure file
>   storage space, set security policies,
>   and delete unused data. With isolated
>   storage, your code no longer needs
>   unique paths to specify safe locations
>   in the file system, and data is
>   protected from other applications that
>   only have isolated storage access.
>   Hard-coded information that indicates
>   where an application's storage area is
>   located is unnecessary.